# Process Managment memory-leak in Windows Server x64?

Tags: windows, memory, 64-bit, memory-leak

After clean install and boot of OS Windows x64 I launched cmd.exe (any other exe) and closed it. Then I launch rammap.exe (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx). On the 2nd page  called "Processes" I sorted list by process name and saw that cmd.exe still consumes memory (4K Private and 16K Page table = 20K). I launched it 2nd time and new item appears in this list (one for every process launch+termination). So every process termination takes 20K of memory away.

If you have software frequently launching and terminating processes on such server OS you will spot that after some days or weeks OS begins to show strange errors (usually about not enough memory). And more days after that everything you have to do is to restart OS. After restarting it works fine for nearly the same period of time.

I registered this problem on every 2008 server R2 x64 (+SP1 and -SP1) and indirectly (rammap doesn't support) on 2003 Server x64.

The problem is not observed on Windows 7 x32 (+SP1 and -SP1).

Screenshot
[image]

See the first step in exploration of this problem [Page table fast growth](https://serverfault.com/questions/173606/page-table-fast-growth)

Can anybody disprove or approve my assumption and observation?
Can anybody tell how to work around this behavior?
Is it bug or is it not?

Comment: Presumably you've created a case with MS for this right?

Comment: Chopper3,
My knowledge of English is not perfect. Please clarify phrase "a case with MS".

Comment: I mean have you called Microsoft.

Comment: Not yet. I have not done it before.

Comment: Could you show the output of `FLTMC` command, ran from an Administrative command prompt?

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you want to close all the "cmd.exe" instances, you may use the TASKKILL command.

```
TASKKILL /IM "CMD.EXE" /F
```

It's a very simple way to end all running instances of a process, always keeping in mind that you show run as Administrator in order to give the program the rights neccesary to finish processes.

Comment: Please try to take note of the publication date of questions, asking the Original Poster to perform debugging steps 7 years later is unlikely to generate a response.... - Also please don't use salutations in questions and answers